# Is there a way to access the metavar default name (parameter name in all caps)?

Tags: python, argparse

I am using `argparse` with Python 3.7, and I want to include the default `metavar` name in the `help` text; for example, if the parameter name is `"source"`, the default `metavar` becomes `"SOURCE"`, and I'd like this text to appear in the help using `"%(metavar)s"` instead of hardcoding it.

I cannot use `"%(dest)s"` for this, because it renders lowercase and cannot be converted to uppercase (or at least I haven't found a way to do so).

Following the `argparse` documentation, I wrote this:

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("-s", "--source", type = open, help = "Blah blah %(metavar)s blah.")
p.parse_args()
```

When I call the program with the `--help` option, I expect `"%(metavar)s"` to turn into `"SOURCE"`, but instead it turns into `"None"`:

```
usage: test_argparse.py [-h] [-s SOURCE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -s SOURCE, --source SOURCE
                        Blah blah None blah.
```

If I set `metavar` to a certain value (for example, `"SOURCE"`), it works correctly, but that would mean that I'd have to manually define that value for every parameter.

Is there a way to use `metavar`'s default value (i.e., the parameter name in all caps) without having to set `metavar = "SOURCE"` or, hardcoding it in the `help` text? I have looked into the documentation, but haven't found anything about it.

Comment: The short version of my answer in @jonrsharpe 's link - what you call the default metavar is generated on the fly when formatting the help. It isn't available for inclusion in the `help` expression.  But you know what it will look like when developing the code, so there's no reason not to hardcode it into the `help` or `metavar`.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. Nevertheless, I'll go with the solution/hack suggested by @anthon in the link.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the `metavar` explicitly by `metavar="foo"`

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("-s", metavar="--source", type = open, help = "Blah blah %(metavar)s blah.")
p.parse_args()
```